# MVC3: How to handle constructor exception in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, coding-style

I have a controller with several action methods requiring the same list of data from a certain database.  Since most of the actions were going to need access to the list, I quickly populated a private member variable with necessary list of data items directly in the constructor of my controller.

All was well and good until the database went down and an exception was thrown in the constructor. Apparently, that circumvents the normal HandleError functionality.

My goal is for this exception to be caught and the user redirected to an error view.

- What is the proper way to load the data for all actions?
- Is it appropriate to put a database call in OnActionExecuting?
- Is there some way to do decorate the specific actions with an attribute that loads the data?
- Am I over-thinking it? *(After all, I could just drop a private method in the controller and call it from each action requiring the data*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers (as objects) are being instantiated **for every request**. Therefore, there is no need to optimize data **within controller** which would be "reused" in many actions (as Jeff Reddy suggested). Unless you call an action method explicitly from another action method (which is bad practice anyway).

Make a private method GetData() that gets data from database and call it in every action.

However, you probably do want to avoid expensive database round-trips that get the same data over and over, then consider using HttpRuntime.Cache. You could save data there on the first call to GetData() and retrieve it from cache on subsequent requests.

Comment: Sergey, you've only reiterated what I've suggested. A private method that gets the data and that is called from each of the actions.  I implicitly suggested caching the list data when I said it's only populated the first time. Subsequent calls would get the list data from where ever it was cached.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the private method and have it populate your list (if it's not already populated) and then return the list. This way your only calling the method to populate it when it's needed the first time, and you take fragile code out of your controller's constructor.  It's going to much easier to handle the exception in your action methods than elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the model inside all your controller actions you could define a [custom model binder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) for a given model and overriding the [BidModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.bindmodel.aspx) method which will query the database and populate this model. Then your controller actions could take this model as action argument:

```
public ActionResult Foo(MyModel model)
{
    ...
}

public ActionResult Bar(MyModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

If you don't need the model inside each action but inside each view you could externalize it as a widget using the [Html.RenderAction helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).